# magento2 Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

Tags: magento2, construct

I am getting `"Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function on parent::__construct($context);`

**Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyTheme\Theme\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{   
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Even if I use `parent::__construct($context, $pageFactory);` instead of `parent::__construct($context);` I get the same error.

Comment: Should remove the '\'.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh from where?

Comment: Remove the '\' from use after namespace

Comment: @SureshChikani I remove the '\' but I still get the same error. I just updated the code.

Comment: Check it with remove cache and generation folder.

Comment: Just run one time upgrade command it will be solved

Answer (score 12):

After a couple hours I found a solution. I had to run the commands below:

1. php bin/magento cache:flush
2. php bin/magento cache:clean
3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. bin/magento setup:di:compile
5. From magento root directory: chmod -R 777 var/*

Comment: Why would like to make each file in var/ executable? Better use `find -type d chmod 777 {} \;`

Answer (score 10):

It means that a old function signature is still cached. If you are during development,

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

might be enough. Otherwise brazuka's answer would help.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:

**1. From magento root directory: chmod -R 777 var/ generated/**

**2. From magento root directory: rm -rf generated/code/MyTheme**

**Reason:**

There might be already generated Interceptor class, then you pass additional dependency injection to the constructor.The interceptor class is not rewrite properly.